# Android Nearby Connection API not available for specific devices

Tags: android, google-nearby, google-nearby-connections

I am building an Android app making communication between two devices.
For this purpose, I am using Google Nearby Connection API and everything is working fine so far.

But specifically on Xiaomi 10X pro, the advertising cannot be established.

Following error is returned:

```
 com.google.android.gms.common.api.ApiException: 17: API: Nearby.CONNECTIONS_API is not available on this device.
    at com.google.android.gms.common.api.internal.zad.zaa(Unknown Source:4)
    at com.google.android.gms.common.api.internal.zaf.zaa(Unknown Source:16)
    at com.google.android.gms.common.api.internal.GoogleApiManager$zaa.zac(Unknown Source:175)
    at com.google.android.gms.common.api.internal.GoogleApiManager$zaa.onConnectionFailed(Unknown Source:95)
    at com.google.android.gms.common.api.internal.GoogleApiManager$zaa.connect(Unknown Source:219)
    at com.google.android.gms.common.api.internal.GoogleApiManager$zaa.zaa(Unknown Source:112)
    at com.google.android.gms.common.api.internal.GoogleApiManager.handleMessage(Unknown Source:145)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:103)
    at com.google.android.gms.internal.base.zap.dispatchMessage(Unknown Source:8)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:224)
    at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:67)
```

The code used to advertise is not far from the Google documentation:

```
private fun startAdvertising() {
    AdvertisingOptions.Builder()
      .setStrategy(Strategy.P2P_POINT_TO_POINT)
      .build()
      .also { options ->
        Nearby
          .getConnectionsClient(context)
          .startAdvertising(
            "card",
            "com.app.my",
            connectionLifecycleCallback,
            options
          )
          .addOnSuccessListener {
            FL.d("Advertising with success")
          }
          .addOnFailureListener { e: Exception? ->
            FL.e("Advertising failed", e)
          }
      }
  }
```

I am digging the internet since but with no success.
I cannot figure why Nearby Connection API would not be available for this specific device / model.

Has anybody already encountered such issue ?

Comment: Does this device have the Google Play Store? Nearby is part of Google Play Services and isn't available on devices without the Play Store.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated by @Xlythe, the device was bought on Chinese market and thus did not have Play Services installed at first.

After adding Play Store and Play Services, everthing works like a charm.